# Inserting a custom select element within a series of mapped input components in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, stack, rendering, sequence

I'm working on a ReactJS project where I have an array of objects. Each object contains props data for a custom input component (**`<Input key={} type={} title={} group={}/>`**) I've built. My typical approach is to map over this array to render each of these input components.

However, I have a specific requirement for the rendered sequence of elements.
for example, If i need the rendered components to follow this order:

```
// start mapping the array and render <Input /> components
// --------------------------------------------------------------
<Input key={} type={} title={} group={}/>
<Input key={} type={} title={} group={}/>


// here i want to insert the Select Element in between the map sequence 
// --------------------------------------------------------------
<Select isActive={} options={} onChangeAction={} optionEvent={}/>

// continue the <Input /> components map sequence
// --------------------------------------------------------------
<Input key={} type={} title={} group={}/>
<Input key={} type={} title={} group={}/>
<Input key={} type={} title={} group={}/>
```

As you can see, I want to insert a custom select element (**`<Select />`**) in between the mapped **`<Input />`** components. I'm trying to achieve this without heavily manipulating the original array or making the code less readable and maintainable.

Is there a conventional or recommended approach in React to map over an array while maintaining a specific order of rendered components, especially when inserting a different component within the sequence?

Any insights or best practices on this would be invaluable...

I incorporated a group key-value pair into the array that contains the prop data. This group key is processed through a reducer, which then assigns a specific className to the div wrapper of each rendered component.

However, I find this approach to be less intuitive and challenging to maintain. While I can employ this type of manipulation or iterate over multiple arrays to map out each group (with each array representing a distinct group), it feels cumbersome. This method requires excessive typing, which seems redundant and inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options (*not really best practices, as those depend on the specific scenario*) are

a) You could either split the array to multiple one and then map over those (if it makes sense for your usecase)

```
const allObjects = [...];
const preSelect = allObjects.slice(0,5);
const postSelect = allObjects.slice(5);

// and when rendering do

preSelect.map(...)
<Select .../>
postSelect.map(...)
```

---

b) Alternatively, if you have a specific logic on where/when to show the select, you could return a `Fragment` with the `Select` and `Input` at that point.

```
allObjects.map((object, index) => {
   if (/* condition to show select */){
    return <React.Fragment><Select .../><Input .../></React.Fragment>
   }

   return <Input .../>
})
```

---

A best practice would be to have your array correctly include the data you need to output the `Select` at the correct place just by iterating over it.

Something like

```
const allObjects = [
   ...,
   {type:'select', ...},
   ...
];

// and then do

allObject.map( object => {
  if (object.type === 'select'){
    return <Select .../>;
  }
  return <Input .../>;
})
```

Comment: As you recommended, I've added the desired element to the array and mapped through it in the same way I previously did. 

If this approach is considered best practice for such scenarios, I'll continue with it. However, I want to ensure there isn't a more optimal solution.